# opsworks/chef databag where to put the json file?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, chef, opsworks

Hello I'm reading this howto:
https://github.com/imoglobe/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/master/user/README.md
but it does not mention where to put the data bag in the cookbook with the list of users in json format..
I have done some searching and answers come up for regular chef and not in AWS opsworks chef.
can anyone push me to the right direction? im sure this is a easy answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to manage login users then OpsWorks has [built in support](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/security-settingsshkey.html) for allowing IAM users to log into instances within a stack.

On to your actual question - data bag support is limited in OpsWorks. Firstly, data bags are not supported at all [prior to Chef 11.10](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-chef11.html).

In Chef 10.10 [you can use data bags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-chef11-10.html#workingcookbook-chef11-10-databag) but data can only be entered via the [custom JSON](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingstacks-json.html) in the stack settings:

> **You cannot create a data bag by adding it to your cookbook repository**.
>   You must use custom JSON.

...

> You create a data bag by using custom JSON to add one or more
>   attributes to the stack configuration and deployment JSON
>   **[:opsworks][:data_bags] attribute**.

This is untested, but your custom should probably look something like:

```
{
  "opsworks": {
    "data_bags": {
      "users": {
        {
          "id": "hsolo",
          "comment": "Han Solo",
          "home": "/opt/hoth/hsolo",
          "ssh_keys": ["123...", "456..."]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could *probably* also set the `[:opsworks][:data_bags][:users]` key at compile time in your Chef recipe using a JSON file from S3 (see [Reading and parsing a JSON file to use in a recipe](http://hipsterdevblog.com/blog/2015/01/03/revisited-retrieving-files-from-s3-using-chef-on-opsworks/) in this blog post) although I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thank you, you are right I ended up using the AWS opsworks system instead of chef cookbook. regarding databags thanks. we do use the latest version so they are supposed to work.

Comment: This worked for me.  Don't forget the underscore in `data_bags`!